# Enviar varios files em um form

Tags: php

como fazer para esse codigo enviar mais de uma imagem em diferentes inputs

```
<form name="myForm" method="POST" action="back_img.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $result['id'];?>">
                    <input name="arquivo" id="arquivo" type="file"><br><input name="arquivo1" id="arquivo" type="file">
```

Alterar

```
<?php
include '../conexao_banco.php';
// verifica se foi enviado um arquivo 
if(isset($_FILES['arquivo']['name']) && $_FILES["arquivo"]["error"] == 0)
{


    echo "Este arquivo é do tipo: <strong>" . $_FILES['arquivo']['type'] . "</strong><br />";

    $arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
    $nome = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];


    // Pega a extensao
    $extensao = strrchr($nome, '.');

    // Converte a extensao para mimusculo
    $extensao = strtolower($extensao);

    // Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
    // Aqui eu enfilero as extesões permitidas e separo por ';'
    // Isso server apenas para eu poder pesquisar dentro desta String
    if(strstr('.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $extensao))
    {
        // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
        // Evita que duplique as imagens no servidor.
        $novoNome = md5(microtime()) . '.' . $extensao;

        // Concatena a pasta com o nome
        $destino = '../img_usuario/' . $novoNome;  

        // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
        if( @move_uploaded_file( $arquivo_tmp, $destino  ))
        {
            echo "Arquivo salvo com sucesso em : <strong>" . $destino . "</strong><br />";
            echo "<img src=\"" . $destino . "\" />";

          try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            // prepare sql and bind parameters
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE user SET arquivo=:arquivo WHERE id=:id;");

            $stmt->bindParam(':arquivo', $novoNome);
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id']);
            $stmt->execute();

            echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Imagem Alterada Com Sucesso"); self.location.href="pag_user.php";</script>'; 
            exit;
            }
        catch(PDOException $e)
            {
            echo "Ops... Erro no servidor: ".$e->getMessage();
            }



        }
        else
            echo "Erro ao salvar o arquivo. Aparentemente você não tem permissão de escrita.<br />";
    }
    else
        echo "Você poderá enviar apenas arquivos \"*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png\"<br />";
}
else
{
    header('Location: pag_user.php');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode acessar aos vários uploads através de um foreach, ou então, se preferir, acessar manualmente (Exemplo: `$_FILES['arquivo']`, `$_FILES['arquivo1']`...)

Caso queira fazer um foreach, pode fazer algo parecido com:

```
    foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
         $arquivo_tmp = $file['tmp_name']; // equivale a $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
    //resto do código

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar o atributo `multiple` no seu `input` para selecionar mais de um arquivo em um único input, ficando assim

```py
<form name="myForm" method="POST" action="back_img.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $result['id'];?>">
                    <input name="arquivo" id="arquivo" type="file" multiple>
```

Desta forma você pode selecionar mais de um arquivo em um mesmo input. Só tome cuidado com o tamanho dos arquivos a serem enviados para não ultrapassar o valor permitido de acordo com sua hospedagem.